# Solve a differential equation by roots of characteristic equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, roots, delay-differential-equations

I read in a paper that solution of a differential equation 
 $$\dot{x}(t) = -cx(t-h)+f(t)$$
where $x$ is a scalar with zero initial condition (for all $t\leq 0$) can be written as
$$x(t) = \int_0^t f(\hat{t})\sum_r{\frac{e^{s_r(t-\hat{t})}}{1+h\,s_r}}d\hat{t}.$$
Here $\{s_r\}$ are solution of characteristic equation $s+ce^{-hs}=0$.

How can this be generalized to system of differential equations with zero initial condition? For example,
 $$\dot{z}(t) = A\,z(t-h)+B\,z+v\, f(t),$$
where $z$ is a vector.
In other words how can we write the solution in terms of characteristic equation roots and integral involving function $f$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your example is still first order--the highest order derivative of the unknown function that appears in the equation is z', i.e. the first order derivative.

Comment: I edited the question, to avoid ambiguity. I meant to say system of differential equations.